# struct on Arduino: function() 'does not name a type'

Tags: c++, function, struct, arduino, typedef

I write a struct for variable and function, but is not work for me. I'm confused...

```
struct Array2 {
    int array[2] = {0, 1};
};

Array2 Digit2Arr2(int x) {
  Array2 v;
  if (x > 9) {
    int y;
    y=x/10; v.array[1]=x-(10*y); x=y;
    y=x/10; v.array[0]=x-(10*y); x=y;
  } else {
    v.array[0] = 0;
    v.array[1] = x;
  }
  return v;
}
```

> 'Array2' does not name a type

Comment: The name of the struct comes after the struct keyword, before the body.

Comment: This one is working just fine. Maybe in older versions of Arduino IDE it wouldn't work. You obviously changed the question, so it confuses everyone looking into this why it shouldn't be working... Anyway in original edit there was anonymous struct, with one instance named Array2 (= variable). You should keep ORIGINAL QUESTION. DO NOT FIX IT in the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highly recommend you read up on how to create structs.

Heres somewhere you can start:

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/47-structs/

Your syntax is wrong in the creation of the struct.

```
struct Array2 {
   int array[2] = {0, 1}; 
};
```